# Enviroment.GetCommandLineArgs() set up

Tags: c#, cmd, args

I want to make a Load event holder. Main point of making this that I could use my program with specific file and get results which are shown in that file. So I want to make this through command line parameters passing.I am using `string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();` . And now I want to check my parameters where

```
args[0] = program.exe 
args[1] = specific_file.json
if
(args.Lenght = 1) return; // non parameters given
if
(args.Lenght =2) // only one parameter given
```

Maybe you could show me so guide or examples how to make it work?

Comment: There are lots of examples of command line parsers – including very complex command line processing – on the web.

Comment: It should read *args.Leng**th***...